# No exception when opening SqlConnection in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am making an application to connect to a local SQL Server database, and I am using the following method to create the connection string and test for exceptions.

```
public void connect(string user, string password, string server, string database)
    {
        connectString = "user id=" + user + ";" +
                        "password=" + password + ";" +
                        "server=" + server + ";" +
                        "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                        "database=" + database + ";" +
                        "connection timeout=5";
        myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectString);
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            isConnected = true;
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            isConnected = false;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            isConnected = false;
        }
    }
```

From my research there should be an exception thrown if the connection cannot be opened, but if I pass nonsense credentials or empty strings no exception is thrown. If I pass in correct information I am able to connect and use the connection string to pull in data. With the bad connection string I get an exception later when trying to fill a SqlDataAdapter with the data.

Also, with the nonsense connection strings myConnection.State is open when I debug and check that.

Is there a problem with my understanding of how the exception catching should work? Am I correct in thinking that the SqlConnection State should not be open when I am unable to connect to the database because of a bad credentials?

Comment: You **do know** that there is a [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class - right? That would make it so much easier to create a connection string (rather than just stringing it together....)

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks for the pointer! I am trying to build this robustly, but I am new to working with a database in C# so I am probably re-inventing the wheel some.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your connection string you have `"Trusted_Connection=yes;"` that will use the current windows account for authentication and will ignore the username, password supplied in the connection string.

See: [Integrated Security -or- Trusted_Connection *from SqlConnection.ConnectionString Property*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> When false, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When
>   true, the current Windows account credentials are used for
>   authentication. Recognized values are true, false, yes, no, and sspi
>   (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to true.
>
> **If User ID and Password are specified and Integrated Security is set to true, the User ID and Password will be ignored** and Integrated
>   Security will be used. SqlCredential is a more secure way to specify
>   credentials for a connection that uses SQL Server Authentication
>   (Integrated Security=false).